# Why does MSVC use the stack needlessly when returning a small struct in a register?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, optimization, assembly

I compiled the following code on MSVC 2013, x64, Release build with /02:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

Point xUnit()
{
    Point p;
    p.x = 1;
    p.y = 0;
    return p;
}
```

The generated assembly code for `xUnit()` is:

```
mov QWORD PTR p$[rsp], 1
mov rax, QWORD PTR p$[rsp]
ret 0
```

Why does it write to the stack and then immediately read back into `rax` to return?

I would have expected:

```
mov rax, 1
ret 0
```

Comment: What you expected is essentially what [Clang](http://goo.gl/VvQPyO) and [GCC](http://goo.gl/RN7Kmx) both generate on gcc.godbolt.org.

Comment: Wow, that is an *extremely* useful tool I didn't know about.  Thanks!

Comment: This function will always be inlined.  Looking at non-optimized code is not useful.

Comment: @HansPassant he says he compiled it with /O2, so I guess something is just a bit wrong with MSVC in this particular case.

Comment: What happens if you define a constructor and then do `return Point( 1, 0 );` ?

Comment: Realizing that `mov rax, 1` also sets the `x` field of `Point` to 0 is a pretty awesome optimization. Would be easy to get it wrong and leave `x` uninitalized.

BTW, all versions of gcc that I checked on Compiler Explorer (the link given by @Columbo) do essentially the same as MSVC:

    `xUnit():
 pushq %rbp
 movq %rsp, %rbp
 movl $1, -16(%rbp)
 movl $0, -12(%rbp)
 movq -16(%rbp), %rax
 popq %rbp
 ret`

Comment: You must compile a complete program in full optimization mode to see how the value is used. With only the function the output may not be the most optimized

Answer (score 3):

X86 version seems to do well (that is generate "mov  eax,1").

My guess is that X86 and X64 versions are separate code bases and optimization found in one target is not necessarily present in the other.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: OP is asking why a particular optimization is not done by a particular compiler. I tested the compiler output for the same program with same flags for a different target (X86) and it did optimize the code. Since MSVC is not a public domain compiler, it is hard to tell why - one can speculate or ask MSVC team directly.